# jquery change/click event on an input

Tags: jquery, click

I have a problem with my eventhandler.

`<input id="menuSelection" type="text" value=""/>`

this field is triggerd from a menu with a value. But my problem is somewhere in the jquery code to get this working more "live"

hierarchybreadcrumb is the menu-id.

```
$('#hierarchybreadcrumb').click(function(){
var text = $('#menuSelection').val();

$.get('exercise/xhrGetValue', {text:text}, function(o){

});
return false;
});
```

this function gets the result but I have to click on the menu once agen to get it working. How do I get this on the first click to send the get-method? or is it some functionalety that can trigger the change on $('#menuSelection')?

thanks for the help and I hope you understand my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I hope I have understood you correctly.  Inputs do not trigger change events unless focus is lost after having focus (in a basic sense)

To make it "live" add a wrapper and use the on

```
$('mywrapperselector').on('click','#hierarchybreadcrumb',function(){
    var text = $('#menuSelection').val();

    $.get('exercise/xhrGetValue', {text:text}, function(o){
    });
    return false;
});
```

worst case:

```
$(document).on('click','#hierarchybreadcrumb',function(){
    var text = $('#menuSelection').val();

    $.get('exercise/xhrGetValue', {text:text}, function(o){
    });
    return false;
});
```

NOW, if you want to trigger the change event, simply do that:

```
$(document).on('click','#hierarchybreadcrumb',function(){
    var text = $('#menuSelection').val();

    $.get('exercise/xhrGetValue', {text:text}, function(o){
          $('#menuSelection').val('some new value').trigger('change');
          //assume you want it in here
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, the $('mywrapperselector') you are talking about, is it a div-tag? Im not with you on that thing.